# For SOQL queries, can "WITH USER_MODE" safely replace "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED"?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, security, field-level-security

When performing static or dynamic `SOQL` queries, should `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` now be replaced with `WITH USER_MODE`? Under what conditions, if any, should `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` still be used given there is also `WITH SYSTEM_MODE`?

If I attempt to replace `SECURITY_ENFORCED` with `USER_MODE`, the Salesforce Extensions in VSCode produce the warning:

> Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation (rule: Security-ApexCRUDViolation)

Is this just a case of the VSCode Extension not being updated yet? (Or that `USER_MODE` is still in beta?)

The Apex Developer Guide talks about `USER_MODE` here:

- [Enforce User Mode for Database Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm)

Salesforce's [dreamhouse-lwc](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc) sample application uses `USER_MODE` in at least one of their controllers.

- [PropertyController.cls :: L94](https://github.com/trailheadapps/dreamhouse-lwc/blob/6aa5b547089ea683210a6faa5bdfaeac62cfc97a/force-app/main/default/classes/PropertyController.cls#L94)

Comment: Are you not getting the error if you have SECURITY_ENFORCED

Comment: VSCode presents an orange, underlined security warning when I use `USER_MODE`. It does not preset any security warnings when I use `SECURITY_ENFORCED` in the exact same places.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We are recommending developers use `WITH USER_MODE` and avoid using the `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`

In fact, at some time in the future, we may likely retire `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`

The `WITH USER_MODE` supports lots of new innovations like restriction rules, scoping rules, and any other security operations for data access and CRUD/FLS that may be added by the platform in the future, so it's sort of future-proof. It also handles complex security use cases better.

Also, it supports SOSL and polymorphic queries and performs far better than using the `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`.

The `WITH USER_MODE` can handle CRUD/FLS for fields in where clause in SOQL or for areas used in relationship query or polymorphic lookup.

You can find more information about why you should prefer `WITH USER_MODE` and avoid `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` in the latest talk at TrailblazerDX 2023 conference, and the link to view the talk is shared below.

https://www.salesforce.com/plus/experience/trailblazerdx_2023/series/Developers_for_TrailblazerDX_2023/episode/episode-s1e1